# Form end tags inside of table creating extra td's?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I've never tried putting two forms inside a single table or putting a form end tag inside a table.   Seems like this should be basic knowlege but I'm having trouble finding anything with Google on this.

I was just curious - if I put an form end tag (<% end %>) inside a table it seems to create about 8 html spaces and the browser seems to take this as an extra td (or something like that).   Visually the table looks exactly like an extra TD was was created by the end tag (which really goofs up how the table looks of course)

Is it possible to put a form end tag inside a table w/o the table getting messy?

```
  <td>
    <%= submit_tag 'Delete Folder' -%><% end %>
  </td>


  <td>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Delete Folder" />        </form>
  </td>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the erb dash syntax around the `form_tag`/`form_for` and the `end`:

```
<%- form_tag do -%>
...
<%- end -%>
```

Note that the `<% %>` syntax now also suppresses whitespace, but it didn't as of Rails 2.3.5.

You should be able to put it inside a table without any weird effects, but tags should be properly nested and you have to either put the entire form inside one `td` tag or around the table. For example you can't do this:

```
<table>
  <form>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Tables just don't like tags inside them in other places.

And you can't do this: (not properly nested)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><form></td>
    <td></form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```